# Flurry Analytics: I see logEvent occurrences in the portal but do not see logError occurrences

Tags: flurry, flurry-analytics

I'm calling both logEvent and logError, but only see the former in the Flurry console.  Do errors show up somewhere else?

```
Flurry.logError("DataUpdater_Error", message: causeOfError, error: nil)
Flurry.logEvent("DataUpdater_Event")
```

[image: Here's a picture of the Flurry Analytics Portal]

In the portal I'm looking under "Events".  Are errors somewhere else?  Or is it just not working?

Comment: This is still happening unfortunately, I'm now prefixing my error (event) names with 'Error_' :(

Answer (score 1):

Flurry's new UI does not have all the features supported yet. I assume they will add these soon...Specific Crashes and user-defined Errors don't seem to be there right now.